# Completely uninstall Adobe CS5

Tags: software, adobe

I once installed Adobe CS 5 as a Trial but now I pre-ordered the new suite. I've deleted the Adobe CS 5 suite, and installed the new suite. But whenever I try to open photoshop for example, the Software Setup pops up and tells me my trial of CS 5 has expired and I need to enter a serial.
I don't know if it will accept my CS 6 serial, but I first want to get rid of all (!) the CS 5 files.

I've tried the [Adobe CS Cleaner](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html) tool, deleting the .cache and .pcd file in */Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PCD*, but it's still asking for a serial... So I'm guessing there are still some files *somewhere*.

So, how do I delete ALL files of Adobe CS 5, so I can start over with a fresh copy of CS 6?

Comment: What version of Photoshop is opening, 5 or 6? If it's CS5 you may want to empty the trash. Did you have to enter your serial while installing CS6?

Comment: 5 is opening and I didn't had to enter a serial for CS6 since it's a trial...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start with the actual uninstaller rather than the cleaner.

- http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/uninstall-creative-suite-cs5-cs5.html

Adobe does do deep integration, and I've been known to just walk away from machines with too much adobe on them. If you feel the uninstaller isn't getting things clean enough, you can take it a step further as follows:

- Perform a clean install of the OS
- use Migration Assistant to bring in the user account rather than setting up a new user on the "clean" Mac
- download the uninstaller onto the new admin account

At that point, you can run the uninstaller to clean out any ~/Library plugins that might be installed. It's overkill, but sometimes a clean start is better than trying to let uninstallers find every copy of files that have been zipped, moved, linked, etc...

Comment: Aren't those uninstallers for Adobe software (Flash, Air, CS...) always installed during the original installation?

Comment: They are - however, I like to always go get the latest uninstaller. I'm notorious for _not updating_ the software and on occasion the uninstaller you have can be out of date or incomplete (or have a bug). In this case, another uninstaller / cleaner has been run, so who knows what is left. The uninstaller should be a unified item - cleaned at the end, but grabbing one removes all doubt whether you have a working tool to clean things up.

Comment: If I do a clean install and bring my user account back with the Migration Assistant, won't the Adobe files be copied as well when restoring?

Comment: Just user library caches and plug ins. These are fairly easy to see, harmless without the new software installed, and the new software will likely overwrite or ignore these files.

Comment: So, I just move migrate the entire user? Don't really know what you mean.

Comment: On step 8 - only select the user account to migrate. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413

Answer (score 1):

Some of this may be repetitive but follow these steps and you should have absolutely positively NO trace of Adobe left on your computer.

- Remove all Adobe fonts from /System/Library/Fonts, /Library/Fonts/, ~/Library/Fonts
- Remove all these additional fonts from the same folders:

  <kbd>WarnockPro-Bold.otf</kbd>               
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightDisp.otf</kbd>         
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldCapt.otf</kbd>          
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightIt.otf</kbd>            
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldDisp.otf</kbd>          
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightItCapt.otf</kbd>       
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldIt.otf</kbd>             
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightItDisp.otf</kbd>       
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldItCapt.otf</kbd>        
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightItSubh.otf</kbd>    
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldItDisp.otf</kbd>       
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightSubh.otf</kbd>         
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldItSubh.otf</kbd>     
  <kbd>WarnockPro-Regular.otf</kbd>           
  <kbd>WarnockPro-BoldSubh.otf</kbd>         
  <kbd>WarnockPro-Semibold.otf</kbd>       
  <kbd>WarnockPro-Capt.otf</kbd>                 
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldCapt.otf</kbd>                  
  <kbd>WarnockPro-Disp.otf</kbd>               
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldDisp.otf</kbd>  
  <kbd>WarnockPro-It.otf</kbd>                      
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldIt.otf</kbd>     
  <kbd>WarnockPro-ItCapt.otf</kbd>               
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldItCapt.otf</kbd>
  <kbd>WarnockPro-ItDisp.otf</kbd>             
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldItDisp.otf</kbd>
  <kbd>WarnockPro-ItSubh.otf</kbd>              
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldItSubh.otf</kbd>
  <kbd>WarnockPro-Light.otf</kbd>             
  <kbd>WarnockPro-SemiboldSubh.otf</kbd> 
  <kbd>WarnockPro-LightCapt.otf</kbd>       
  <kbd>WarnockPro-Subh.otf</kbd>
- Search for and remove any files labeled 'Adobe' or 'Macromedia in all of these folders

```
$find . -name "*adobe*" -print
```

```
    /Applications                       /System/Library/
    ~/Applications                      ~/Documents/
    /Applications/Utilities             ~/Library/
    ~/Applications/Utilities            ~/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/Adobe
    ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe
    ~/Library/Internet Plug-ins/Adobe
```

- Remove these explicit folders

```
    ~/Documents/Updater/
    ~/Library/Acrobat User Data/
    ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe
    ~/Library/Applications/Macromedia
    ~/Library/Application Support/Macromedia
    ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe PDF
    ~/Library/Caches/Acrobat
    ~/Library/Caches/Adobe
    ~/Library/Caches/Opera Cache
    ~/Library/Preferences/Acrobat
    ~/Library/Preferences/Adobe
    ~/Library/Preferences/Adobe
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.adobe
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.adobe
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.macromedia
    ~/Library/Preferences/Dreamweaver
    ~/Library/Preferences/Opera Preferences
    ~/Library/PreferencePanes/AdobeVersionCue
    ~/Library/receipts/com.adobe
    ~/Library/StartupItems/AdobeVersionCue
```

- Search for and delete the following files and/or folders:

```
    ACE2CACHE
    Acrobat
    Acrobat Webcapture Cookies
    Adobe
    Adobe GoLive 7.0 Prefs
    Adobe Illustrator CS Settings
    Adobe InDesign
    Adobe Photoshop 8.0 Paths
    Adobe Photoshop CS Settings
    Adobe UM
    Com.Adobe.Acrobat.Pro6.0.plist
    Com.Adobe.Acrobat.Pro7.0.plist
    Adobe Registration Database
    Adobe Installer.tmp
```

- Open terminal

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

- Restart

Answer (score 0):

To completely uninstall Adobe Apps you need to run the uninstaller in `Applications/Utilities/Adobe Installers`.